# Salesforce SandboxPostCopy fails on Sandbox refresh

Tags: apex, sandbox-refresh

I have used some code to helps us with sandbox refreshes back in 2018. For the past several months, I noticed that when we refresh an existing box, the admin emails do not get updated. Just recently I dove in and found that i am getting a DML error. If I spin off a new box, the code executes without issues.
Here is the error:
Update failed. First exception on row 3 with id #####; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.
The username already exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email address). : [Username]

I found this article, but looks like the issue was resolved: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318796&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Has anyone experienced this? I think it would be confusing if I start updating the user names in the code as well. Here is the code I am using:

```
global static void fixAdminEmail(){

        List<User>adminsList = [select id, name, email from User where Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' and IsActive = true and Email like '%.invalid'];

        List<user> updatedAdminList = new List<user>();
        
        for(User sa : adminsList){

            String removePhrase='.invalid';
            sa.Email=sa.email.remove(removePhrase);
            updatedAdminList.add(sa);
             
        }
        
        if(updatedAdminList.size()>0){
            
            Update updatedAdminList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so, the error is telling you that the 4th User retrieved has a duplicate username. When you run this query in the sandbox (after the refresh - which user is this?. The Knowledge Article says the issue will resolve itself in "a while" - sadly, "a while" is not good enough for a post copy script -- you might try and schedule a job (+5 mins from NOW) that does this work rather than doing it synchronously in the postCopy apex.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If I run the script after the refresh, I do not get any DML Errors. The script executes as expected and is updating all of the admin email addresses. I will look into running the job 5 min after the refresh.

Comment: Oddly enough, after 24 hours, I did receive an email from one of the refreshed orgs. The day before I ensured that my automation failed with the DML error. That said, it looks like salesforce retried the code and resend the email. This is really odd. Performing more tests to confirm my theory.